# How to convert a data frame column in python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

After reading from large excel I have the following data

```
Mode Fiscal Year/Period Amount
ABC  12.2001            10243.00
CAB   2.201               987.87
```

I need to convert the above data frame as below

```
Mode Fiscal Year/Period Amount
ABC   012.2001          10243.00
CAB   002.2010            987.87
```

need help in converting the Fiscal Year/Period column.

Comment: "need help" with what code?  You're left-padding a string with 0s, easy enough to look up on line.  What have you tried that didn't work?

Comment: What is the issue, exactly? Have you tried anything, done any research? Stack Overflow is not a free code writing service, nor is it meant to provide personalized guides and tutorials. See: [ask], [help/on-topic], https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users.

Answer (score 1):

It is always easier for us and you will get better help if you provide your attempts at the solution (your code).

Try this,

```
import pandas as pd
```

Recreating your data

```
data = {'mode':['abc', 'cab'], 'Fiscal Year/Period':[12.2001, 2.201]}
```

And put it in a dataframe,

```
data=pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Convert the column to a str,

```
data['Fiscal Year/Period']=data['Fiscal Year/Period'].astype(str)
```

And use [zfill()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.zfill.html#pandas.Series.str.zfill) to fill with zeros

```
data['Fiscal Year/Period'].apply(lambda x: x.zfill(8))
```

yields,

```
0    012.2001
1    0002.201
Name: Fiscal Year/Period, dtype: object
```

Comment: good solution but the answer doesn't match his intended output, you'll need to do some splitting and use different string formatting techniques to match the output.

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, you can just `zfill` and `ljust`

```
s = df['Fiscal_Year/Period'].str.split('.',expand=True)
s[0] = s[0].str.zfill(3)
s[1] = s[1].str.ljust(4,'0')

df['Year'] = s.agg('.'.join,axis=1)

print(df)

  Mode Fiscal_Year/Period    Amount      Year
0  ABC            12.2001  10243.00  012.2001
1  CAB              2.201    987.87  002.2010
```